# Fetch only one row in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, fetch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

simple question here.

I have a SELECT query

```
SELECT FROM friendzone WHERE ID = '$editID'"
```

I am sure this is going to give me only one row as result, cause ID's can't be duplicate in my DB.

How can I access the column values?

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

I think this is useless since I don't have to make any array.. I have only one row!

If I don't put it into a While cicle, and try to do e.g.

```
.$row['ID'].
```

I get:

```
mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Are you trying to select a row with a specific id? If so do you want it to always select that row or do you want it done dynamically?

Comment: Your SELECT statement is invalid - you have no columns specified or `SELECT *` Your query fails, and you don't do any error checking.

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new
>   code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and the
>   [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the
>   [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared
>   statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use
>   [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this
>   article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose
>   PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Try with:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friendzone WHERE ID = '$editID'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

print_r($row);
```

MySQLi code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM friendzone WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $editID);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

print_r($row);
```

Comment: Obviously the SQL Query was done with the code you posted

Comment: +1. Please also provide the mysqli and/or PDO code to do it, as to have no excuse for not doing it.

Comment: Thank you! I have chosen MySQLi and using it now :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably your `$query` is equal `false` because something went wrong, try `mysql_error()` to see whats wrong.

And 2 small advices:

1. would be better to use `PDO` od `mysqli` as mysql_* functions are deprecated.
2. use at least `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape the value before putting it into SQL string

Answer (score -2):

Since I don't know what columns your trying to select the general syntax for select is

```
"SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM friendzone WHERE ID ='$editID'"
```

Or if you want to select all columns just type

```
"SELECT * FROM friendzone WHERE ID = '$editID'"
```